# Intellij how to open source code from stack trace during debugging

Tags: debugging, intellij-idea, stack-trace

Intellij: how to open source code from stack trace during debugging?

```
stack trace
--------
method1
method2
mothod3
```

Source code can be opened for the method on the top (method1), but method2 and method3 are grey, and source can not be opened.

Comment: We need more details. What are the exact methods in the stack trace? Are they methods in your own code? Usually if they are greyed out then they are methods in 3rd party libraries and the source code isn't available.

Comment: They are in a different project.

Comment: If you have access to the source code for the other project, then you can configure IntelliJ to use that source code. For example if the other project is open source, you can download the source. Otherwise you are SOL.

Comment: But it does not have a link for me to attach source code in stack trace.

Comment: Source code can be attached to the libraries or you can add content/source roots. See https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/configuring-content-roots.html and https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/creating-and-managing-modules.html#working-with-module-dependencies.

Comment: The source code jar for the gradle library is automatically downloaded and attached, seen from Project Structure -> Libraries. But the method is still greyed out.  Verified that the class/method  is in the source code jar.